# ffmpeg png to mov keep exact colors

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, png, quicktime, color-space

When I convert a PNG sequence to a h264 (yuv420p) movie and read the color values via FFmpeg's rawvideo pipe output, the values on each pixel is slightly modified.

This is how I write my image:

```
import numpy as NP
from PIL import Image

# Set up colors.
pixel_array = NP.array(
    [
        [
            [0, 0, 0],
            [255, 0, 0],
            [0, 255, 0],
            [0, 255, 0],
        ],
        [
            [125, 125, 125],
            [0, 255, 0],
            [0, 255, 0],
            [0, 255, 0],
        ],
    ],
    dtype=NP.uint8,
)

Image.fromarray(pixel_array).save("test.png")
```

When I read the values back using ffmpeg's pipe, the values are all correct:

```
# Read image.
process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ffmpeg", "-i", "test.png", "-f", "rawvideo", "-pix_fmt", "rgb24", "pipe:"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
process.wait()
data_from_png = NP.frombuffer(process.stdout.read(), NP.uint8).reshape([-1, 2, 4, 3])
```

However when I convert to mov first and read the pixel values of the mov, numbers are all different:

```
# Convert png to a movie
process = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i",
        "test.png",
        "-c:v",
        "libx264",
        "-pix_fmt",
        "yuv444p",
        "-preset",
        "slow",
        "-crf",
        "18",
        "-y",
        "test.mov",
    ],
)
process.wait()


# Read mov.
process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ffmpeg", "-i", "test.mov", "-f", "rawvideo", "-pix_fmt", "rgb24", "pipe:"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
process.wait()
data_from_mov = NP.frombuffer(process.stdout.read(), NP.uint8).reshape([-1, 2, 4, 3])
```

Output from reading the png versus mov:

```
data from png:
array([[[[  0,   0,   0],
         [255,   0,   0],
         [  0, 255,   0],
         [  0, 255,   0]],

        [[125, 125, 125],
         [  0, 255,   0],
         [  0, 255,   0],
         [  0, 255,   0]]]], dtype=uint8)

data from mov:
array([[[[  0,   0,   0],
         [254,   5,   0],
         [  3, 239,   5],
         [  0, 255,   3]],

        [[111, 131, 117],
         [  0, 255,  36],
         [  0, 255,   6],
         [  3, 254,   0]]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Am I doing wrong when I'm converting the pngs to mov? Or is there a problem with the way I'm reading the mov?

Comment: RGB values are not going to be the same due to color conversion, and due to compression artifacts. I think H.264 encode blocks with size 16x16. Try image size 16x16. Try `-crf 0`. Try `libx264rgb` codec instead of `libx264` (remove `yuv444p` when using `libx264rgb`). Try `libx265` with `-crf 0` and image size 16x16. Note: you are asking about `yuv420p`, but using `yuv444p`.